# How do I select last array per key in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given the following php array

```
$a = array(
    array('a'=>'111','b'=>'two','c'=>'asdasd'),
    array('a'=>'111','b'=>'one','c'=>'sdvsdfs'),
    array('a'=>'111','b'=>'three','c'=>'vbndfgn'),
    array('a'=>'222','b'=>'nine','c'=>'dfhfnd')
);
```

how can I return only the last array per array key 'a'?

Desired result:

```
$new = array(
    array('a'=>'111','b'=>'three','c'=>'vbndfgn'),
    array('a'=>'222','b'=>'nine','c'=>'dfhfnd')
);
```

Comment: Sounds like a crappy way to format this.  Can you get it in a more multi-dimensional format?

Comment: @LeviMorrison: +1. Can you make it more of a hash-table like structure, if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I'd try to store it in a better format that makes retrieving it a bit easier.  However, if you are stuck with your format, then try:

```
$a = array(
    array('a'=>'111','b'=>'two','c'=>'asdasd'),
    array('a'=>'111','b'=>'one','c'=>'sdvsdfs'),
    array('a'=>'111','b'=>'three','c'=>'vbndfgn'),
    array('a'=>'222','b'=>'nine','c'=>'dfhfnd')
);

$tmp = array();
foreach ($a as $value) {
    $tmp[$value['a']] = $value;
}

$new = array_values($tmp);

print_r($new);
```